# Pass data From Activity, to Fragment with Activity, then back once option is selected

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Im try to get data from an activity that someone has selected. Here is more understanding of what im doing.

I have an activity called PromptsActivity which lists all the Options that a user can choose from. ie. "I want a red shirt instead of a white one".

So in PromptsActivity I do a network call that gives me the Prompts I need the user to choose from.

When they click on one of the Prompts it takes them to another Activity that has a fragment inside it.

In the onClickListener I have an intent as follows:

```
    radioButtonLL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(PromptsActivity.this, PromptsRadioButtonActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(PARCEL_OPTIONS_KEY, prompt);
        startActivityForResult(i, RADIO_BUTTON_CODE);
      }
    });
```

So when they click the Prompt, it takes them to the relevant activity and fragment with the prompt object so I can display the data needed for the user to choose from.

1. Red - $5
2. Blue - $5
3. Green - $2

So for each of these options I have an onClickListener that when they select an option it

```
  radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
      if (isChecked) {
        mInterface.selectedOption(radioButtonOption);
      }
    }
  });
```

The activity that is hosting the Fragment is implementing the interface as so:

```
public class PromptsRadioButtonActivity extends BaseActivity implements SelectedDataInterface {

... other code

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
      super.onBackPressed();
      if (mOption != null){
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra(PromptsActivity.RADIO_BUTTON_SELECTED, mOption);
        setResult(PromptsActivity.RESULT_OK, i);
        finish();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void selectedOption(Option option) {
      if (option != null) {
        mOption = option;
      }
    }
```

Now in the PromptsActivity I have overridden the onActivityResult method and here is my code in that method at the moment:

```
      @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PromptsActivity.RADIO_BUTTON_CODE) {
      Option option = data.getParcelableExtra(RADIO_BUTTON_SELECTED);
      Log.e("radio button result Ok", option.getText());
      Toast.makeText(PromptsActivity.this, "Selected Radio button is: " + option.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Log.e("radio bttn result null", "failed");

  }
```

For some reason, the Log.e("radio bttn result null", "failed"); line is always called and I cannot for the life of me figure out why?

What I am trying to do here is to pass the option that was selected back to the PromptsActivity so I can, in the end show in the list of Prompts what they have selected, as well as send the option that was selected back to the webservice.

Comment: Log.e("radio bttn result null", "failed"); line is always called because you have not placed it inside else i guess

Comment: Thanks, that was a stupid moment, i have made that change, but for some reason the Toast still doesnt run

Comment: could show what value you are getting in requestCode and resultCode..

Answer (score 1):

The reason `Log.e("radio bttn result null", "failed");` gets printed is because you did not include it in an `else` block - as such this code get executed regardless - please enclose it in the else block like this:

```
@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PromptsActivity.RADIO_BUTTON_CODE) {
      Option option = data.getParcelableExtra(RADIO_BUTTON_SELECTED);
      Log.e("radio button result Ok", option.getText());
      Toast.makeText(PromptsActivity.this, "Selected Radio button is: " + option.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
else{
    Log.e("radio bttn result null", "failed");
}

  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a stupid moment for me, although the Toast never does actually run either way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of RESULT_OK try this may be help you out,

```
     if (resultCode == PromptsActivity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == PromptsActivity.RADIO_BUTTON_CODE) {
         ..........
      }else{
         .........
      }
```

Comment: Thank this didnt work, i had a blonde moment and forgot the Else statement which i feel stupid about, so after changing this from RESULT_OK to PromptsActivity.RESULT_OK and moving the Log.e to the else block, the code still always runs the Log.e for some reason and never toasts the Selected radio button?